# Positive semidefinite kernel matrix from Gower distance

Tags: classification, categorical-data, distance, kernel

I have a dataframe with continuous and categorical variables and I want to obtain a kernel matrix for classification. The kernel matrix must be symmetric and positive semidefinite, so that no eigenvalue is negative. I started with Gower distance matrix for mixed data, which is not positive semidefinite. I tried to transform the Gower distance matrix into a positive semidefinite and symmetric kernel with the function `D2Ks`of `MiRV`package in R, with no success. I tried also to apply the approach of page 799 in `Zhao, Ni et al. “Testing in Microbiome-Profiling Studies with MiRKAT, the Microbiome Regression-Based Kernel Association Test” American journal of human genetics vol. 96,5 (2015): 797-807.` with no success, as well. I always obtain a indefinite kernel matrix with positive and negative eigenvalues. Any suggestion?

Comment: Check this out https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/nearPD.html

Comment: Oh! Wonderful suggestion! Will check it out!!

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [nearPD](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/nearPD.html) in R to convert a matrix to its Nearest Positive Definite counterpart.

Comment: Perfect suggestion! Thank you!